# How Can I download linux .whl file with dependencies on windows

Tags: python, download, pip

I want to download Linux_x86_64 Python Packages(.whl) with dependencies
on windows10, Python 3.6.8 version. 
like that:

```
pip download 
--only-binary=:all: 
--platform linux_x86_64 
--python-version 35 
--implementation py 
--abi none 
-d "C:\my\download\folder" 
pandas
```

But It takes an Error like:

```
 Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pandas
```

Help me Please...

Comment: Try `--implementation cp` (CPython instead of generic Python) and remove `--abi none`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It solved...
Just like this code in linux computer.

```
pip download package
```

Answer (score -1):

I download scientific Python packages for windows from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pandas). Kindly make sure you install the other dependencies from the mentioned site.